# Using mousedown/mouseup in js, not able to change the position of elements?

Tags: javascript, html, css, addeventlistener

I have created a set of dots using div tags inside a div tag. My need is when I drag the last dot, the whole set of dots should move and sit where mouse pointer is placed at present. I tried achieving it using `addeventlistner` for mouse clicks but failed in my attempt.

Can someone point out the intuition in the segment below?

```js
var dots = document.createElement("div");
dots.className = "dots";
document.body.appendChild(dots);

var dotarray = [];

for (index = 0; index < 10; index++) {
  dotarray[index] = document.createElement("div");
  dotarray[index].className = "dot";
  dots.appendChild(dotarray[index]);
}

dotarray[9].addEventListener("mousedown", function(event) {
  if (event.which == 1) {
    var currentMousePointerPos, latestMousePointerPos;
    currentMousePointerPos = event.pageX;
    dotarray[9].addEventListener("mouseup", function(event) {
      latestMousePointerPos = event.pageX;
      if (currentMousePointerPos != latestMousePointerPos) {
        dots.style.marginLeft = currentMousePointerPos + latestMousePointerPos;
      }
    })
  }
})
```

```css
.dot {
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.dots {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 135px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The immediate answer to your question is that `dots.style.marginLeft` needs to be equal to a string, containing the units.
Hence, this would work:

```
dots.style.marginLeft = ((currentMousePointerPos+latestMousePointerPos) + "px");
```

*However:*

1. Your `mouseup` listener only listens to the event that the mouse click is released when it's over the element, so it doesn't do much. If you assign the listener to the whole document, the listener's function would be activated no matter where the `mouseup` event occurres.
2. `currentMousePointerPos + latestMousePointerPos` doesn't represent the final position of the mouse.

If we fix these two issues the will code still operate weirdly, because the left side of the `dots` element is set to the mouse's last position.
Therefore we just need to subtract the element's width from the `marginLeft` property.

The following code combines everything I've mentioned:

```js
var dots = document.createElement("div");
dots.className = "dots";
document.body.appendChild(dots);

var dotarray = [];

for (index = 0; index < 10; index++) {
  dotarray[index] = document.createElement("div");
  dotarray[index].className = "dot";
  dots.appendChild(dotarray[index]);
}

dotarray[9].addEventListener("mousedown", function(event) {
  if (event.which == 1) {
    var currentMousePointerPos;
    // Notice how the listener is bound to the whole document
    document.addEventListener("mouseup", function(event) {
      currentMousePointerPos = event.pageX;
      dots.style.marginLeft = ((currentMousePointerPos-dots.offsetWidth) + "px");
    })
  }
})
```

```css
.dot {
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.dots {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 135px;
}
```

Comment: Did you mean in your first point that mouseup event is listened on  dotarray[9] only after mousedown event is finished which is not possible in my scenario.So i have to have the mouseup event for different node which in this case is "document" right?

Comment: I beleive if I subract the dots width with currentMousePointerPos  ,it changes to the current mouse pointer position

Comment: How to subract the numeric value from the expression.Help me out here. dots.style.marginLeft = (currentMousePointerPos + "px") - expresssion ???

Comment: This works beautifully: `dots.style.marginLeft = ((currentMousePointerPos-dots.offsetWidth) + "px");`

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you are looking for?

> You should use the `mousemove` event instead to detect any dragging
>   after `mousedown`.

```js
var dots = document.createElement("div");
dots.className = "dots";
document.body.appendChild(dots);
var dotarray = [];

for (index = 0; index < 10; index++) {
  dotarray[index] = document.createElement("div");
  dotarray[index].className = "dot";
  dots.appendChild(dotarray[index]);
}

dotarray[9].addEventListener("mousedown", function(event) {
  if (event.which == 1) {
 window.addEventListener('mousemove', move, true);
    /*var currentMousePointerPos, latestMousePointerPos;
    currentMousePointerPos = event.pageX;
    dotarray[9].addEventListener("mouseup", function(event) {
      latestMousePointerPos = event.pageX;
      if (currentMousePointerPos != latestMousePointerPos) {
        dots.style.marginLeft = currentMousePointerPos + latestMousePointerPos;
      }
    })*/
  }
});

window.addEventListener("mouseup", function(event) {
 window.removeEventListener('mousemove', move, true);
});

function move(e){
    var div = document.getElementsByClassName('dots')[0];
  div.style.position = 'absolute';
  div.style.top = -8+e.clientY + 'px';
  div.style.left = -135+8+e.clientX + 'px';
}
```

```css
.dot {
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.dots {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 135px;
}
```